# Writing a generic `string_to_float<T>` without overhead compared to `std::stof`

Tags: c++, c++20, if-constexpr, c++-attributes

I want to write a function `string_to_float` with template parameter `T` such that `string_to_float = std::stof`, `string_to_float = std::stod` and `string_to_float = std::stold`, when `T = float`, `T = double` and `T = long double`, respectively. My attempt was the following:

```
template<typename T>
T string_to_float(std::string const& s, std::size_t* pos = nullptr)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, float> || std::is_same_v<T, double> || std::is_same_v<T, long double>,
        "T is not a built-in floating point type");

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        return std::stof(s, pos);
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        return std::stod(s, pos);
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long double>)
        return std::stold(s, pos);

    return T{};
}
```

However, I worry about the `return` statement. While the static assertion will already fail in that case, I don't want to produce an additional misleading compiler error when `T` is not default constructible.

I also want to make sure that the code produced by an invocation of `string_to_float` is really exactly the same as if I had used `std::stof`, `std::stod` or `std::stold` directly (assuming, of course, that `T = float`, `T = double` or `T = long double`).

This is why I didn't remove the last if-clause checking for `T` being equal to `long double` and simply returned `std::stold(s, pos);` in the last line. On the other hand, at compile time the it is already clear if `T = float` or `T = double` and in that case, there would be a `return` before the `return` in the last line; so the compiler might ignore that `return` anyways.

I've also looked at the [attribute specifier sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) and hoped that there is some kind of `[[unreachable]]` attribute so that the compiler really knows that the code below this line will never be reached.

Comment: You can use specialization instead.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars, this already has the three overloads you're looking for.

Comment: "hoped that there is some kind of [[unreachable]] attribute" - [`std::unreachable` appeared in C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable)

Comment: It's probably a good idea to constrain the template: `#include <concepts>`/`template<std::floating_point T>`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't want to produce an additional misleading compiler error when `T` is not default constructible.

Then, don't include that last `return T{};`. It's not ever going to be used anyway.

Example:

```cpp
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

template <typename T>
T string_to_float(std::string const& s, std::size_t* pos = nullptr) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        return std::stof(s, pos);
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        return std::stod(s, pos);
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long double>)
        return std::stold(s, pos);
    else 
        static_assert(always_false_v<T>,
                      "T is not a built-in floating point type");
}
```

The `always_false_v` variable template instead of just `false` is needed for old versions of the compilers that doesn't implement the new rules according to [CWG2518](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2518.html).

Examples (the versions are inclusive):

- gcc up to 12.3
- clang up to 16
- icx up to 2023.1.0
- msvc still won't be able to deal with just `false` even in the current latest version.

Comment: Ted, why do you use `always_false_v<T>` rather than just using `false` directly?  `if constexpr` ensures that code is eliminated unless no earlier condition matches.

Comment: @TobySpeight Not all compilers have implemented that yet so they need this roundabout way to make it `false`. I think clang up to ver. 16 will fail for example. I added some examples.

Comment: @TobySpeight CWG2518 allowing static_assert(false) in a non-evaluated template context was only accepted in Feb 2023! Before then if constexpr() {} else static_assert(false, ...) was ill-formed. CWG2518 was accepted as a DR so compilers apply it in all standards modes and not just C++23. Something so new to the language as of 7-8 months ago isn't in a lot of released compiler versions yet.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of static assert and type checks you can provide 3 specializations prohibiting generic template.

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
T string_to_float(std::string const & s, std::size_t * pos = nullptr) = delete;

template<>
float string_to_float(std::string const & s, std::size_t * pos)
{
    return std::stof(s, pos);
}

template<>
double string_to_float(std::string const & s, std::size_t * pos)
{
    return std::stod(s, pos);
}

template<>
long double string_to_float(std::string const & s, std::size_t * pos)
{
    return std::stold(s, pos);
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAOykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzGakAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn6BdpgOWQ1NBCWRMXGJyQqNza15HeP9YYPlw0kAlLaoXsTI7BzmCWHI3lgA1CYJbk5jxJisJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenF2HAN3ePDwSYLBSBn%2BJzcBAAnilGKxXgAVb4PWGHD5GAD6RFRVFoqCYBAgY3QIBAKOAhzQDDGxzMADZkaRkQRCcS8AAvTDow4AKkOaQUbwAIocGF5aLQUgRiEsBYcsPQQQkrA8fv9AcDMKCEfcsTiCAziJ90ahMdjcfjGUSSWSBJTzLSFPSCRbWezddzeUsfiZ/Ir7oc/YcLeaUGtdRrTlSzGEAG6oADWnwZqCoxwArG4GOYzCcff7DpcCOsGAymWMk/j6e7s57/PzPX8AUDcerTpr0GtovQ9QaMdrTY7iRKE%2BSbTS6cWnWyOW70h6ld6frnA0y0F5Qy3w5no3GE6X0Kn05mqw9c/nC%2BOBxhyzyZ0fHjW6/cVY35W5NdijDL252SYbjTqzSWg4fsOoajva54ZJOrrXgos53jm/pLkSK5rq%2BG5mJGDAxvGH6lrQe4mGmGYYbeJ6YAWxBFv2eHoFelYKtWtZKg8YS6iwTBhBAcFeghfoAPR8YcXhKIcSYyjU5GYHuVBeAw3QCIcYAcEiP49iaeIgRBQFfDSDpBpBLqcnBuYCamFgAO6EAghxIicgqsQAdE5C7%2BgJqlGr2BCgqxNwQJmCQOVmGEegxx7%2Bu5f64qCnm%2Bf5gWZiFvFdmiak6qCbZeB2zbYH5GEBUFZiJS5foRTFpzvqSGVZbFeXxcFt5ekx9wcCstCcCmvB%2BBwWikKgnCvpY1jImsGyvDsPCkAQmgtSssYgCmGgORoXAJCtCT%2BMtGj%2BNSACcgRtRwkiddNvWcLwCggBok3TSscCwEgmCqF0q4kOQlBNMACjKIYNRCAgqDmV1E1oICdC4lk33hLQf0A11PUgykdDDMAK3JAjSPEBEMJnaQ6P0MQADyq4w4DJ2PV09zEJ9OPk8gDT4F1vD8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOo3U6HoBhGCg1jWPoeDRBdkArKg4pZBdHAALQKwSdmmINlhmBohwKwA6mItDazrj0SkwhtQughiOMghtxMQJC8KgUa23gWCS1xqzrJsegEmEkO/f9pPcLw5nEEwKScDwrXtcdfOnRw2BPcgL3EIcqgABzUgr1KSIcwDINbK2BYcEADVYlj0rghAkFSq1LLwU180ss0gJIO0OTtGcZ9SZgdztZgJBoCT6JwR2kHDDs4xdV0N1oTfDxwZgxz1fUcPXN0rE7xAZM4khAA)

Comment: Your specializations are incomplete.  How is the compiler going to choose one?

Comment: @MarkRansom ¿What do you mean by "incomplete"? They are full specializations with explicitly supplied float, double, l. double parameters. There shouldn't be any issues with selection of the proper one given that template parameter is provided at the point of invocation.

Comment: The float, double, and long double are not parameters, they're return values.  Return values are not considered in overload resolution.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think you are confusing template specializations with overloaded functions. There is only one overload candidate - template function `string_to_float`. Matching specialization of this function will be selected based on the explicitly supplied template parameter.  float, double, and long double are indeed returned values, but they also define template parameter for corresponding specialization. It could've been like `template<> float string_to_float<float>`, but that's just a bit redundant. I've added OC example, just in case.

Comment: Pretty convincing demo.  But I still don't understand how the compiler chooses between the 3 nearly identical specializations since none of them contains a template parameter.

Comment: It chooses by the caller explicitly specifying which instantiation to use.  You might as well use three different names (for example, `stof`, `stod` and `stold`).  The only thing we've gained is that you can call it from a template function (e.g. `template<std::floating_point T> foo() {  … string_to_float<T>(s) `).

Comment: @MarkRansom Each of them contains a template parameter. It's just present instead of `T` as a return type, not written explicitly inside of angle brackets.

Comment: @MarkRansom When matching explicit specializations, the _type of the whole function_ has template argument deduction performed against types of candidate function templates, i.e. `float(std::string const&, std::size_t*)` against `T(std::string const&, std::size_t*)`. In this deduction, the template argument can be deduced from the return type as well. It is a bit confusing that the template argument deduction differs from that in a function call where instead argument/parameter type pairs are matched individually, but it makes sense, since there is no apriori return type in the function call.